# does umake update its applications automatically?

Tags: apt, software-installation, updates, automatic, ubuntu-make

Will the applications I install through `ubuntu-make` update themselves automatically? Like when I install something with `apt-get` or like when I add a repository.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.

Automatic update is not supported by `umake`. You need to reinstall software when a new version becomes available (unless the software package itself has built in update functionality).

Umake simply downloads the latest version available from the official websites and doesn't give you much option in terms of versioning (besides sometimes having a *stable* and a *beta* version).

Comment: Source: https://github.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-make/issues/327

Comment: so if I want to update a program I should just use `umake --remove` then install again using umake? _(say it doesn't have built-in updating)_

Comment: Yes, so you may prefer the PPA approach more if that annoys you. umake just tries to make installing reconfigured software packages easy so you don't have to waste time setting up.

Comment: I wish umake was more capable of doing things on its own instead of manually doing everything.

Comment: Snaps are a good modern alternative: https://snapcraft.io/ (or even flat pack https://flatpak.org/ )